# Objective C - Accessing Normal C Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, arrays

I am making a game that assigns a label a question from a regular C array.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++) {
    basketball_numbers1[i] = (arc4random()%999)+100;
    basketball_numbers2[i] = (arc4random()%999)+100;
    for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
        int first = basketball_numbers1[i];
        int second = basketball_numbers2[i];
        basketball_questions[j] = [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d + %d", first, second] retain];
        basketball_answers[j] = [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", basketball_numbers1[i] + basketball_numbers2[i]] retain];

    }

}
```

This code works and printed the questions and answers to the console no problem before I commented them out.

But when I'm running the emulator and type in the correct answer, the same questions stays on the label, even though the count (variable used to increase the index of the array) increases, which I confirmed via NSLog.

Some other notes: when I had manually put in values for the array, it worked no problem. Also I added in the 'retain' to the end of the array after doing some research, which actually eliminated some problems I was having before this, but I'm not sure if retain/release are used in regular C arrays or just NSArray.

Here is the code that reads in the textfield upon a button click.

```
- (IBAction)basketball_click:(id)sender {

basketball_input = self.basketball_textfield.text;
NSLog(@"INPUT: %@", self.basketball_textfield.text);

if ([self.basketball_textfield.text isEqualToString:(basketball_answers[count])]) {

    NSLog(@"THEY ARE EQUAL");

    isCorrect = TRUE;

    self.basketball_textfield.text = @"";

}

...

if(isCorrect) {

    NSLog(@"Retain Count: %d", [basketball_questions[count] retainCount]);

    correct.text = @"CORRECT!";
    basketball_right++;
    count++;

    NSLog(@"COUNT: %d", count);

    question_label.text = basketball_questions[count];

    NSLog(@"NEW QUESTION: %@", basketball_questions[count]);

}
```

Comment: It will be much easier for someone to help if you fix the formatting of your code and boil your issue down to a simple example of your problem.

Comment: You can still make these a lot shorter. Try producing a minimal example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: I looked into NSArray but I didn't think it was necessary, plus it would be a pain to change some of the code, but if I need to use it I will.

Comment: any reason you are NOT using arc?  it would help alot with all the memory management your having to do.

Comment: I have never heard of arc for starters. Is it easy to implement when I'm this far along? I just feel like I'm missing one thing somewhere when I populate the array.

Comment: The retain is fine there. You do not use it on the regular C array. You use it on the object of type NSString that happens to be part of a C array. However, I suggest using NSMutableArray. At least that retains for free when you add an object to the array. Although I do not belive that this is your problem here.

Comment: I am willing to change to a mutable array, but if you don't think that's the problem I don't want to go through and change everything.

Comment: So you are getting the correct anwers and questions printed on the console but the text of the label does not change. Are you sure that question_label is properly linked with the label that is currently displayed? Did you try NSLog'ing question_label? Doing so you find out at least whether it is nil or not. Just use NSLog (@"%@", question_label);

Comment: That printed out the same question. But I don't understand why it would if I KNOW the count is increasing and I'm calling the array at that increased count.

Comment: It's as if the whole array gets populated by only that first entry, which makes me believe it has to be a memory issue.

Comment: What is the type (declaration) of `basketball_questions`? Array of `id`?

Comment: Well, all 30 entries of the array basketball qutestions do have the same content. They all show "1+2" if 1 and 2 happen to be the random numbers of the 45th iteration of i. You go for j from 0 to 30 and fill the array 30 times with the same value. You do that 45 times - for whatever reason. All 30 entries of the answsers array will contain "3" if first and second happen to be 1 and 2. What do you aim to achieve with this loops?

Comment: basketball_questions is an array of 'NSString's

Comment: The 45 is supposed to be a 30.
I wanted to assign a random number to each numbers1 and numbers2 and then add them together a display in the array 'basketball_questions'

If that's not clear, please let me know and I will reiterate.

Comment: It should be an array of pointer to NSString, not an array of NSString.

Comment: It is a pointer to NSString, sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: Hermann is right - check your loops.

Comment: But you don't. Even if you change the 30 to 45. With the two nested for loops in the way you are using them you will use 45x45 iterations to fill 45 entries of the arrays all with the same random numbers. What is the sense in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++) {
    first  = (arc4random()%999)+100;
    last   = (arc4random()%999)+100;
    basketball_questions[i] = [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d + %d", first, second] retain];
    basketball_answers[i] = [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", first+last] retain];

    }
```

Comment: Wow I feel really dumb and I was researching so long about arrays and it was a stupid mistake in the for loop.

It won't let me upvote since I'm new, but I really appreciate everyone's help, especially you Hermann.

Cheers and thanks again.

Comment: Thats what Stack Overflow is about. Sometimes it is a wee bit of information missing and sometimes it is one of these cases where you just don't see the wood for the trees.